# Can  mean Garden?

Tags: meaning, sumerian

A Wiktionary edit from [27 August 2009](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Eden&diff=next&oldid=7073280) changed the etymology of the English "Eden" being some Sumerian "e-den", then in [23 July 2015](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Eden&diff=next&oldid=33574301), it was assigned as the sign .

But [at that time](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%F0%92%82%94&diff=35337677&oldid=24644784),  was undefined in Wiktionary.

And [known compounds](https://www.sumerian.org/suml-r.htm) have Sumerian "eden" meaning "steppe":

> MÍ-eden-na: she-ass of the steppe ('female' + 'steppe' + genitive).

Is there any basis that there's anything in Sumerian that sounds like English "Eden", that has the meaning of "Garden"?

Comment: I have no idea what the actual answer to this question is, but I would just point out that Sumerian  doesn’t _have_ to also have the meaning ‘garden’ for the etymology to work. The Biblical word is Hebrew, and if at any point it meant ‘garden’ (which Wiktionary doesn’t currently say it did – just ‘paradise’), the shift in meaning from ‘open land’ to ‘garden’ could have happened within Akkadian or Hebrew after the Sumerian word was borrowed.

Answer (score 3):

The logogram EDEN can have [a few different meanings](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/psl/html/extra/x16c.html), but none of them are especially close to "garden". [Nor do I see](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/psl/html/extra/x129.html) any compound logogram like É.DEN or E.DEN, though the compound É.KÚRUN "liquor room" exists (KÚRUN is another reading of DEN).

A shift from "steppe, plain" to "garden" or "paradise" seems plausible, but I don't know of any evidence for it.

Comment: with all due respect, EDEN "back, upper side" alligns perfectly with my childhood experience in granny's garden. It is behind the house on a slight slope, and my understanding is that adverbial prepositions are exceedingly common in such cases. Close the back door when you come down, and don't touch the apples.